# How to deal with large amount of data fetching from firebase realtime database in flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I am creating blog application where at a starting level the data is less so the data fetching is faster. But as growing data the app load all the dat at a time from firebase in snapshot so how I can deal with the increasing data in flutter. I checked in android their is a method known as pagging is present to deal with large amount of data but i can't find any resources for flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination for your project.